# Round off to the nearest 10 000 Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have two variables one for decimal numbers and one for integer.
Now, i add the decimal numbers with each other and the integers with each other then multiply the sum of decimal numbers and the sum of the integers. 
My problem now is i want to round them off to the nearest 10 000

So, if 2,54 * 40 000 = 101600 i want my div to display 110 000. Is this possible? 
I never know what the sum of the decimal numbers or the integers are, i just use two variables

Comment: Divide by 10000, call Math.round and multiply by 10000

Comment: but 110000 is not the nearest to 101600, it should be 100000

Comment: I suggest you look at the math object: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math which provides useful stuff for doing Math in JS. Hope this helps!

Comment: Math.round probably works in this manner: essentially you just divide by the level of precision, add 0.5, drop the decimal places, and multiply the level of precision.

Comment: Thank you everyone for the help! With your help i figured out.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

```js
Math.round(101600 / 10000) * 10000 // --> 100000
Math.floor(101600 / 10000) * 10000 // --> 100000
Math.ceil(101600 / 10000) * 10000 // --> 110000
```

Comment: I had to do like this.

var sum = pricep * price;
var result = document.getElementById("res");
result.innerHTML = round * Math.round(sum / round);

Answer (score 1):

```
var round = 10000;
var result = round * Math.round(answer / round);
```

Answer (score 1):

Had to do this recently. Here is a function I wrote to do this automatically.

```
function getRoundedZeros(value, up){
        var roundto = '1';

        for(i = 1;i < value.toString().length; i++){
            roundto = roundto.concat('0');
        }

        roundto = parseInt(roundto);

        if(up === true){
            return Math.ceil(value / roundto) * roundto;
        }else{
            return Math.floor(value / roundto) * roundto;
        }
    }

    rounded = getRoundedZeros(UNrounded, true);
```

I hope it helps someone :)